# Calling a Stored Procedure in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, ora-00900

This should be something fairly simple and straight-forward but for some reason I can't get it to work.  I've created my SProc like so:

```
create or replace procedure zadmit_migrate_data (zadmit_seq_no number)
is
    thisPIDM number;
begin
    select pidm into thisPIDM
    from saturn.zadmit_core_data
    where pk_seqno = zadmit_seq_no;

    if thisPIDM is not null then
        dbms_output.put_line('thisPIDM is NOT null!');    
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('thisPIDM is null!');
    end if;
end zadmit_migrate_data;
```

And now I've trying to call it like this:

```
call zadmit_migrate_data(4);
```

And then I get this error:

```
ORA-06575 Package or function is in an invalid state.
```

So I tried this:

```
execute zadmit_core_data(4);
```

And instead get this error:

```
ORA-00900 Invalid SQL statement.
```

It might be less time consuming to point out where I'm going right, but if anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong that would probably be more useful.  :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but - in this case the `else` branch will never be hit right? If the select statement returns nothing then a NO_DATA_FOUND exception will be raised, so I don't see the point in having the else condition.

Comment: @Sathya - you're wrong.  There is nothing to indicate that PIDM is mandatory, so it is quite possible to find a record but have a NULL in that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this

```
SQL>  alter procedure zadmit_migrate_data compile;
SQL>  show errors
```

Given the simplicity of your procedure, it shouldn't be hard to diagnose the resulting error stack.

Comment: Thanks.  This was the easiest way of finding out what was going on given the answers shown.  Turns out my SProc wasn't recognizing the table so I moved into the same schema as the table and all is good.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't your execute statement be "execute zadmit_migrate_data(4);" ?

At any rate, running this command:

```
SELECT object_name FROM user_objects WHERE status='INVALID';
```

will tell you if you procedure is valid or not.

Executing your CREATE or REPLACE ... command, then immediately executing the command

```
SHOW ERRORS
```

should tell you what compilation errors were encountered.

Comment: You can get more immediate feedback on PL/SQL compilation issues if you use a tool like Oracle's SQL Developer to write the packages.

That said, knowing how to do everything with SQLPLUS and a plain text editor is a real benefit if you get stuck without the fancy tools.

Answer (score 4):

If you Google for error [ORA-06575](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora06575.php), you find:

> You tried to execute an SQL statement
>   that referenced a PLSQL function that
>   is in an invalid state. This happens
>   when the function is compiled with
>   errors.

You can resolve this by:

> Correct the errors and then re-compile
>   the function. Then re-execute the SQL
>   statement.

Once your procedure compiles, you could execute it like:

```
begin 
    zadmit_migrate_data(4);
end;
```